# Pandas position into an excel

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone knows how can I insert a dataframe into an excel in a desired position ?

For example, I would like to start my dataframe into the cell "V78"

Answer (score 2):

there is `startrow` and `startcol` argument in the `.to_excel()` method

```
df.to_excel('excel.xls', startrow=78, startcol=24)
```

Comment: Spot on, I thought this would overwrite so didn't look into it but looking into it that is clearly the best answer

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which may or may not fit your requirements.

I would not directly import it into an existing Excel file which may contain valuable data and furthermore keeping the files separate may be of use one day.

You could simply save the dataframe as an Excel file;

```
df.to_excel('df.xls')
```

And in the Excel file that you want to insert it into create an object of type file and link the two that way. [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/517833/embed-an-excel-document-into-a-worksheet-in-another-excel-document).

Personally keeping them separate seems better as once two files become one there is no going back. `You could also have multiple files this way for easy comparisons, without fiddling row/column numbers!`

Hope was of some help!